# How to display/export an image on an excel spreadsheet with cfcontent

Tags: coldfusion

I have a cfcontent tag exporting an excel spreadsheet, and I am are trying to place a logo on top of the excel spreadsheet.I have tried displaying the logo  with an image tag, a cfimage tag, and none of the tags display the image on the spreadsheet. The output of the spreadsheet just displays the image as "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location". The image is not in the root directory. Is there any other way to display/export an image on a cfcontent

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  

<style>
<!--table
page
{mso-page-orientation:landscape;}
-->
</style>  
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images/Logo.jpg" /> 
    #TheVaribleforExcelOutput#
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the html tags when you are attempting to export to excel?

Comment: The html tags are for styling the excel spreadsheet with bootstrap, and any other styling as well.

Comment: I think Dan's point was the above generates *HTML*. While Excel can interpret it, it is still just HTML, not a "true" spreadsheet. That is relevant because the rules for html versus binary spreadsheets are very different.

Comment: Following up on Leigh's comment, html tags were a simple and effective way of generating spreadsheet content until Office 2007 was introduced. Then it stopped being effective.

Comment: Dan and Leigh, I was wrong in placing the html tags. You guys are correct, the stylesheet is simply ignored. However, i had a style tag for the page which was actually the style sheet the spreadsheet was using. I will remove the tags from the cfcontent tag.

Comment: Binary spreadsheets do not use html or css. So again, I suspect you are NOT actually exporting to an Excel spreadsheet. But instead, something excel can open - ie html/xml.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your answer, but an Excel spreadsheet is going to be a standalone file. There's no "host" associated with it. So if you want an extermal resource attached to it you will need an absolute path as in:

```
<img srce="http://myexample.com/images/logo.jpg">
```

Not sure that will work, but give it a shot. I seem to remember something similar in the distant past. :)

Comment: I have tried absolute path and the way you recommended as well with but still not getting the output.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it ***http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-796e.html***

First we read the image and then have it placed in an image output i.e. in an image source.

```
<cfscript> 
    myImage=ImageRead("http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif"); 
    ImageWrite(myImage,"google-logo.gif"); 
</cfscript> 
<p>This image has been downloaded by ColdFusion:</p> 
<img src="google-logo.gif"> 
<p>This is the original image:</p> 
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif"/>
```